# Why fast before a V02 max test?

Tags: vo2max

A few sources online, like [this](https://formula.ffc.com/stories/employee-stories/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-a-vo2-max-test-why-you-should-get-one/#:%7E:text=Are%20there%20special%20dietary%20restrictions,for%2024%2D12%20hours%20before.) one, say that an athlete should fast for 4 hours and abstain from caffeine before a standard lab V02 max test in which a mask measures air inhalation and expiration. By what physiological mechanism would food or caffeine affect results in a V02 max test?

Answer (score 2):

For caffeine, it is a mild stimulant. Especially if you are not used to drinking caffeine, it can artificially elevate your heart rate, and give a false reading. That is why the advisory against alcohol and smoking/nicotine, because those can alter your heart rate as well.

I could not find specific reasons for the fasting, and a few say to eat up to 3 hours before the test rather than 4. Based on previous readings, when your body is digesting it is more active than it is in a resting state, so my assumption would be that the testing site wants to avoid anything that could throw off the test. (RMR testing has similar restrictions listed).

Comment: I wonder why heart rate or digestion would matter, though -- do those affect air expiration?

Comment: Maybe the thing about eating is just that they don't want people throwing up all over their fancy equipment.